# Testing before production using GitHub Actions fails

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, testing, aws-lambda, github-actions

I am using Github Actions to test my Lambda function before deployment. I am new to Github Action and running a practice project. Everyother jobs in the workflow works fine but the test job keeps giving this role error even though there is a role attached to it. Here is my code:

```
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: upload
    steps:
        - name: Configure AWS credentials
          uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
          with:
            aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
            aws-region: us-east-1
        - name: Create test function  
          run: |  
            aws lambda create-function \
              --function-name test-function \
              --runtime python3.8 \  
              --code S3Bucket=my-github-action-89675,S3Key=${{ github.sha }}.zip \  
              --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler \
              --role arn:aws:iam::${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/lamda-github-action-role
        - name: Wait 30 seconds  
          run: sleep 30  
        - name: Destroy test function  
          if: ${{ always() }}  
          run: aws lambda delete-function --function-name test-function
```

This the error I get:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

aws: error: the following arguments are required: --role

Error: Process completed with exit code 252.
```

Any idea on what to do would be appricated!

I expect the test job to excute but it keeps giving error

Comment: Is it a public github repo? If yes, can you share the url?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure it out. White spaces were the issue. I did it with one line and it solved. I then put the code back in its previous state and tried again and it also worked.

Comment: White spaces where? Perhaps a diff might be handy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Does it behave the same if you quote the parameters? Where I've used expansions - be it from shell variables or input/secrets, I usually quote them (shellcheck expects it). An unexpected newline in any of them would split the command.

```yaml
run: |  
            aws lambda create-function \
              --function-name test-function \
              --runtime python3.8 \  
              --code "S3Bucket=my-github-action-89675,S3Key=${{ github.sha }}.zip" \  
              --handler lambda_function.lambda_handler \
              --role "arn:aws:iam::${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}:role/lamda-github-action-role"
```

Comment: it does give the same error when I quote the parameters.